# Acronis Vs Win10 Backup

Tags: windows-10, windows-backup, acronis-trueimage

I'm a long time user of Acronis for making saftey images and just upgraded to Win10.  Win10 has an image backup feature and was wondering the advantages / disadvantages (reliability, ease of use, anything else) to using Win10 Backup vs Acronis.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I have tried both and I would say that the main advantage of acronis would be the ability to automatically make multiple, incremental backup images so you could choose to revert to any one at any time as well as extract files from any of them. The windows imaging backup only allows for one image at a time. Acronis also has many more options and flexibility with where you can store the image, how often to backup, etc... The cons are that acronis is not free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "System image" is a far cry from a *full disk image*! To create and to *validate* a complete image that can be reliably restored, stick with complete disk imaging software, such as Acronis, or the tools [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) and [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm). A complete disk image has enabled me to recover from hard drive failure (and SSD's also die), and from unrecoverable changes made to the system and to boot sectors due to updates and to my own (rare ;-) errors.

Comment: I thought a system image WAS a disk image.  That makes the choice easy.  I've been saved by the disk image many times also.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, after 4 days of panic I'm back to the same place.  Acronis, which I've used for years, stopped working on my machine after version 2012.  I thought upgrading to Win10 would fix it but not.  On both Win7 and Win10, after installing and a reboot the machine goes BSOD on me.  I recovered the first Acronis Win10 image and that to goes to a BSOD.  Unforgettably, I backed up AFTER installing  Acronis 2021 and got into a catch 22.  I had to roll back to Win7 and Acronois 2012 to get back.  I lost some data and a bunch of time.  Now I need to find an imaging solution that works.

Comment: As mentioned above, my experiences with personal use of Reflect and of DriveImage XML have been positive, and both are free. The first is a bit more elaborate, requiring a short installation, the second is bare-bones, and requires a separate download for a Linux-based rescue disk.

Comment: Reflect worked perfectly.